# I want to implement an Z transform Equation in C (with saturation limits)

Tags: microcontroller, c, code

I will start from the beginning . I had a PI controller with saturation limits (+4 and -2) whose Laplace equation is as follows (0.05s + 0.5)/s. Sampling time of 40 micro seconds

Using Tustins method I have converted this equation in the Z domain , which is
F(z)=(0.05001 - 0.04999z^-1)/(1-z^-1)

If I am not wrong the output equation after taking **inverse z transform is =
Y(i) = 0.05001*U(i) - 0.04999*U(i-1)  + Y(i-1)**
Saturation limits : if output is greater than 4 the output is 4 and if output is less than -2 then output should give -2

here Y(i) is output ,U(i) is input and U(i-1) is previous input and Y(i-1) is previous output
I am assuming the previous input and output value should be set to zero initially

**I need to implement this equation in C and don't know how and confused**

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. Saying you are confused will not get you a good answer. Not trying a bit harder and demonstrating that in your question is good to do.

Comment: It depens if you trying to do just a simulation or controll of real system. The math equations are mainly the same for both but in simulation you must run a controlled system equation also with simulation step time usully far higher than sampling time.

Comment: Edit: simulation step time usually far smaller than sampling time

Comment: Show us all of your attempts so far. Tell us what you **do** understand. This sounds a lot like a homework problem and we don't hand out homework solutions here.

Answer (score 1):

You said

> if output is greater than 4 the output is 4 and if output is less than -2 then output should give -2

Just convert that sentence into code!

This method assumes that you are implementing
`Y(i) = 0.05001U(i) - 0.04999U(i-1) + Y(i-1)` directly in the code as such,
and not in some other form like Direct-II form etc.

Just follow the code that implements the above line by these lines.

```
if (Y(i) > +4) then Y(i) = 4;
if (Y(i) < -2) then Y(i) = -2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the equation really is

> Y(i) = 0.05001U(i) - 0.04999U(i-1) + Y(i-1)

You can write that in C as...

```
int main()
{
  //Define variables

  //This is the inputs to the system.
  //I just chose some numbers at random
  double U[]={0,1,3,7,8,11,17,15,0,1,37,16};
  
  //Get the length of the U array.  Needed later in program.
  const int U_length = sizeof(U)/sizeof(double);

  //This is the outputs of the system
  double Y[U_length];
 
  //handle first computation differently, since don't have prior values.
  Y[0] = 0.05001 * U[0];

  //Run the system for the values from index 1 and onwards.
  for(int i = 1; i < U_length;i++){
    //compute Y.
    Y[i] = 0.05001 * U[i] - 0.04999 * U[i-1] + Y[i-1];
  }
  //At this point Y contains the outputs.
    return 0;
}
```

You can put the code ito an online compiler tool to play with it and test changes.

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler